# Waiting while FileSystemWatcher is monitoring directory

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to monitor a log file for changes. My code is working, and does everything it should. However, as I want this to run as a windows service and be constantly monitoring I'm not sure of the proper way to set it into a waiting state. Here is what it's doing at the moment.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
            log_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            log_watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToFile);
            log_watcher.Filter = recent_file.Name;
            log_watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            log_watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            log_watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            //do rest of stuff OnChanged
            while (true)
            {

            }
    }
```

And then just a simple:

```
    public static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File has changed");
    }
```

What would be a better way in a windows service to do this?

Comment: That is not a windows service code, just a console app. First create correct sample where you have a message pump (like a winforms code) which responds to "start", "stop" etc.

Comment: @L.B trying to make sure my code works before I put it in a service because it is easier to debug imo

Comment: But a console app is not a right way to test. use at least a winforms app

Comment: What is in the while(true) block? This will utilize 100% CPU. In a Windows service, you just initialize your FileSystemWatcher in the OnStart method and do nothing else. The service is then running, waiting for events, consuming 0% CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a message pump using Application.Run() from WinForms.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
// The class that handles the creation of the application windows
class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext {

    private MyApplicationContext() {
        // Handle the ApplicationExit event to know when the application is exiting.
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);

        log_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        log_watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToFile);
        log_watcher.Filter = recent_file.Name;
        log_watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        log_watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        log_watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    public static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("File has changed");
    }

    private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("File monitor exited.");
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // Create the MyApplicationContext, that derives from     ApplicationContext,
        // that manages when the application should exit.

        MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext();

        // Run the application with the specific context. It will exit when
        // all forms are closed.
        Application.Run(context);

    }
}
```

See [Run(ApplicationContext)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_Application_Run_System_Windows_Forms_ApplicationContext_) on learn.microsoft.com.